# CiviCRM contribution tab not graying out "refunded" contributions 5.16

Tags: contacts, theme

one of our end users noticed that on our civicrm 5.16 install where we use drual 7 'seven' for our civicrm administrative theme, refunded transactions are no longer clearly "grayed out" or made clear they were refunded. not sure if this was a change in civi versions or a setting. any leads? thank you!

Comment: Can you check if this patch for a similar issue helps? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1391 / https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15846

Comment: I won't have time for a week or so, but I'll do it then, sorry, our conference is happening.